# How to reset develop branch on remote to master

Tags: git, github

I have develop & master branches, my develop branch is messy now and i would like to reset it and make it as a copy of my master then push it to the server.

I'm not sure if merging the master into develop will make both of them identical. after trying

```
git branch -f develop master
git checkout develop
```

I get the following message

> Switched to branch 'develop' Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by
>   34 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.   (use "git pull" to update
>   your local branch)

I want to update the remote too.. how do I do this?  how do I get around all this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this will **rewrite history** and anyone else that is working off of an old copy of the origin's develop branch will need to update in a similar fashion.  Otherwise things will get very sloppy.

```
# Delete your local develop
git checkout master
git branch -D develop

# Recreate your local develop, based on origin's master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b develop

# Push and overwrite the sloppy develop on the origin
git push origin develop --force
```

Comment: Instead of deleting `develop`, perhaps rename it to keep it around for a while, just in case. `git branch -m bak-develop develop`

Comment: Good point, @janos, probably worth keeping it around locally in case you need it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard master
git push --force origin develop
```

The commands you mentioned should also work, you are just missing the push.